# Add a button to PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager, about-box, pagertitlestrip

I have an application that features video and text content in a View Pager (the only functionality is to swipe left and right to change screens with content).

Now I need to add an "About" screen to the application. To be able to do that I'd need to add three-dots-button **"..."** (I don't know what is the proper name of this). And it turns out there is no other place apart from `PagerTitleStrip` line to add this button. If I add the button to some other place I'll need to use a separate area with only this button which will just waste space on screen. That's why I have a question:

**Question:** How to add a button to `PagerTitleStrip` in View Pager? Or, if you know an alternative way, what would be the other place to put **"..."** button so that it doesn't waste space?

I'll appreciate any suggestion. I suspect there might be some other way to add About page. At the moment I just don't know where to put it keeping interface elegant.

Answer (score 0):

> you can add menu file for this. Example

```
    MenuTest.java

    public class MenuTest extends Activity {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.tmenu, menu);

            // return true so that the menu pop up is opened
            return true; 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.feeds:
            break;
        case R.id.friends:
            break;
        case R.id.about:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
```

> And my XML file is tmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/feeds"
    android:title="Feeds"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/friends"
    android:title="Friends"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="About"/>
</menu>
```

Let me know if it helps you

Comment: this code helps you to create "..." option in your app

Comment: Thank you. I know how to create a menu. The question is **how to add it to PageTitleStrip area of a View Pager**. Please read the question accurately.